# Taylor series approximation in Harris corner detection

Tags: image-processing, opencv, linear-algebra, taylor-expansion

While watching through the computer vision lecture on [interest point detection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4mMhuLHrsQ&list=PLd3hlSJsX_ImKP68wfKZJVIPTd8Ie5u-9&index=4), computing $E(u,v)$ requires computing the quantity
$$E(u,v) = \sum_{x,y}(I(x+u,y+v) - I(x,y))^2$$

In the lecture, $I(x+u,y+v)$ is approximated as $I(x+u,y+v) \approx I(x,y) + I_x(x+u - x) + I_y(y+v -y)$.

The 1st degree taylor polynomial approximation about point $(a,b)$ is given as $$f(x,y) = f(a,b) + f_x(a,b)f(x-a) + f_y(a,b)(y-b)$$

I do not see how to reconcile the equation given above with the $1$st degree taylor approximation about point $(a,b)$ ?

Comment: If the lecture you’re following has that equation, which makes no sense, I suggest you find a better lecture to follow. On the other hand, your Taylor expansion is wrong as well.